# Why is it mandatory to set grid-area property to all html elements to leave an empty cell?

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to make a grid of 2 columns and 4 rows and I want that the cells are filled in this way :

```
'image empty-cell'
'image text'
'image text'
'image empty-cell'
```

I've tried to do this in this way and it doesn't work because the first and the last row cells of the second column aren't empty :

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "image ."
  "image header"
  "image paragraph"
  "image .";
}

.img {
  grid-area: image;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="https://josepicado.com/portfolio/stackoverflow/img.png">
  <h1>Stack overflow logo on the left</h1>
  <p>Stack overflow logo on the left</p>
</div>
```

But if I assign the grid-area property also to my h1 and p elements (code below), it works, why?

```
h1 {
  grid-area: header;
}

p {
  grid-area: paragraph;
}
```

I thought that CSS would have left the cells empty in any case, not only if all elements have got the grid-area property assigned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/):

> This property specifies named grid areas, which are **not associated with any particular grid item**, but can be referenced from the grid-placement properties. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#grid-template-areas-property)</sup>

Then

> A sequence of one or more "." (U+002E FULL STOP), representing a null cell token.
>
> A null cell token represents an unnamed area in the grid container.

Basically with `grid-template-area` you define named and unnamed areas that are not associated with any item and are empty. Either you explicitely reference an area to place an item or that area can be used to automatically place an item

> An item can be placed into **a named grid area** (such as those produced by the template in grid-template-areas) by specifying **the area’s name in grid-area**

and

> A grid item can be **automatically placed into the next available empty grid cell**, growing the grid if there’s no space left.

In your example if you define nothing you will have this:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "image ."
  "image header"
  "image paragraph"
  "image .";
  border:1px solid;
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="https://josepicado.com/portfolio/stackoverflow/img.png">
  <h1>Stack overflow logo on the left</h1>
  <p>Stack overflow logo on the left</p>
</div>
```

The image will be place in the first empty cell (the first `image` area). The title in the next one (the first `.` area). The `p` in the next one (the second `image` area).

By explicitely specifying the place of the image, the other will be automatically placed in the first `.` area and the `header` one

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "image ."
  "image header"
  "image paragraph"
  "image .";
  border:1px solid;
  height:300px;
}

img {
 grid-area:image;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="img" src="https://josepicado.com/portfolio/stackoverflow/img.png">
  <h1>Stack overflow logo on the left</h1>
  <p>Stack overflow logo on the left</p>
</div>
```

In other words, named and unnamed area are exactly the same. The only difference is that you can reference the first one with its name while you cannot with the second one. An unnamed area can be referenced by its indexes.